# Long running task in background

Tags: background, ios5

I made an app, that downloads and parses xml data from server every 7 minutes.

I want it to work in backgound most of the time, so if there are any changes this app could send a local notification.

I read Apple's requirments for long running background tasks, and there is no appropriate category:

```
For tasks that require more execution time to implement, you must request specific permissions to run them in the background without their being suspended. In iOS, only specific app types are allowed to run in the background:

Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
Newsstand apps that need to download and process new content
Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories
```

Any advices?

Comment: may I know the reason why you want to download the xml from the server every 7 minutes?

Comment: ... if there are any changes this app could send a local notification

Answer (score 1):

Create a NSThread, instead of having an infinite loop with sleeps, you'd be better off using an NSTimer. You can initialize it with timerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats: and then schedule it on the run loop your background thread.